# Is using input parameters instead of local variables more efficient in C?

Tags: c, variables, optimization, parameters

Consider the two functions below.  Both functions compute the number of times a character appears in a string with a specified length.

```
    int str_get_num_occurrences1(char * str, char c, unsigned int len){
        if (!len)
            len = strlen(str);

        int res = 0;
        int n = len;

        for ( ; n--; )
            if (str[n] == c)
                res++;

        return res;
    }

    int str_get_num_occurrences2(char * str, char c, unsigned int len){
        int res = 0;

        if (!len)
            len = strlen(str);

        for ( ; len--; )
            if (str[len] == c)
                res++;

        return res;
    }
```

Obviously, the two functions do the same thing.  Besides the fact that the first function is a little bit more readable than the second, is the second function more efficient since it avoids a local variable?  I'm sure that these particular functions are really too simple to measure a true difference.  I'm asking in more of a general or theoretical way.

Are there reasons why a user should avoid using input parameters as temporary storage (besides readability)?  I'm not asking about pointers, where the input could be changed by the function.  Does the compiler interpret the two functions differently which could cause function one to be preferred?

I searched through the questions, and I did find some related questions but none that I could find discussed the efficiency.

Comment: Build with optimizations enabled, then run each function a couple of million times and measure. You can also compare the generated code of the two functions and see if they differ. My guess? It won't matter at all.

Comment: That was my guess too, and I did do that.  The difference is way too small to measure, but I am asking in a more general light.  I'm asking more in the sense that, if a local variable can be avoided...should it be?

Comment: Forget that. The compiler will optimize both as it likes, and it doesn't care whether the variables in play are local variables or parameters. Write readable code and forget about such pointless micro optimisations.

Comment: Why `for ( ; len--; )`, when you could've written `while(len--)`? or even `while(*str++)` if you don't want to/need to read past the terminating nul character

Comment: First and foremost write readable, simple and maintainable code. Then if it turns out to be a bottleneck (after measuring and profiling) you can start worrying about optimization.

Comment: Compiled with a reasonable modern compiler and using an appropriate calling convention, both versions could probably even end up with the exact same machine code. As long as the compiler is able to put the values in a register (in your examples that seems perfectly possible), it will do so and eliminate the local variable completely.

Comment: At least in my eyes, using parameters as temporary storage looks fishy - Maybe I have seen too many cases where someone wanted to return a value through them - Assigning a value to a parameter thus immediately triggers a red light. At least for that reason, I would disregard it.

Comment: I don't think you need to be bothered with such minute details which handled quite well by modern compilers. Just ensure your logic is correct and functionality is met.

Comment: "Is using X instead of Y more efficient in Language?" 1) Measure it. 2) If you care about micro-optimisations, you'll be using an optimising compiler, which will treat local variables and input parameters as practically the same thing.

Comment: I know the general rule that one should write, readable code first and foremost.  I don't mean this question to be specific to these functions, it was more of an example of what I was trying to get across.  If this was something that I needed to do in my personal work, I'd use the readable example.  I meant this question to be more aimed at the how the difference between how the input variables and local variables are interpreted.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, because I didn't think about using a while loop...I guess I could have.  What if the string is not nul terminated?

Comment: @tofro, your first response is more like what I am trying to get at.  So, the input variables are essentially treated as the same as local variables?  I was really curious if both functions could end up being interpreted as the same in the end.  Thank you.

Comment: @therickaman: Arguably, a string missing the terminating character is indicative of a bug elsewhere, but having the length parameter passed to the function then would be the safest bet. If that argument then is `0`, and you rely on `strlen`, the behaviour will be undefined

Comment: @therickaman: I've updated my answer to explain the eval examples a little, and to address the question you raised (strings that aren't terminated)

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Write the code you find easiest to read/write/maintain. The difference between your functions will probably disappear when you compile with optimizations.

You might want to think about a couple of things that you can do to write a more flexible function, or at least: code that is easier to read. This answer will focus more on coding style, than the question ***Which is best, X or Y***, because the answer will almost always be ***That depends on Z***

---

Given that you're allowing the call to pass a `0` value for the string length, you could just write something like this:

```
int get_char_count(const char *str, char c)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(*str++) {
        if (*str == c) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

That, to me, looks like the least amount of code, it's easy to read, and easy to maintain.
The drawbacks are:

- Strings with `'\0'` characters in the middle (ie `char[][]`) can't be processed in full in a single call using this approach
- Not possible to get the char count in a *part* of the string.
- Strings containing `'\0'` chars can't be processed in full

If you want to support those use cases, you'll have to add a length argument. But even then, I'd just add it to the function, and not call `strlen`:

```
int get_char_count(const char *str, char c, unsigned int len)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (!len) {
        while(*str++) {
            if (*str == c) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count; // return early
    }
    //len is given
    while (len--) {
        if (str[len] == c) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now that I'm able to specify how many characters to iterate over, rather than to return on `'\0'`, I can use this function, for example, to count how many occurrences of a given character are in an array of strings:

- Example: [count in `char[][]`](https://eval.in/641372)
- Example: [cont in part of a string](https://eval.in/642084)
- Example: [string with nul-chars](https://eval.in/641374)

The first case (`char [][]`) works because of how the arrays are stored in memory: An array is a contiguous block of memory, and all values are stored in succession. If you know the total size of said block, you can use a `char[][]` as though it is one big string. The result being: only 1 function call is needed to count a character in all elements of the array.

The last case is pretty much the same thing, because the string in the example is actually how an array of strings is stored.

The second example (counting in partial string) is self-evident: rather than specifying the length of the full string, you can specify the number of characters you want to check...
The same approach can be used for strings lacking a terminating nul character

---

Because this is a fairly trivial function to implement, it's common to see most of the brackets being omitted:

```
while (*str++)
    if (*str == c)
        ++count;
//or even
while(len--) count += str[len] == c;
```

The last version is technically valid, but it's not as easy to read. Omitting brackets for one-line if's and simple loops is fairly common, but has been the cause of bugs, like [the `goto fail` bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code#Examples) from a few years back.

One last style-related thing:
When using the pointer to iterate over the string like I did in the first snippet, some will tell you that the best thing to do is to create a local pointer to increment:

```
int get_char_count(const char *str, char c)
{
    int count = 0;
    const char *local = str;
    while(*local++) {
        if (*local == c) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The obvious advantage here being that you're not losing the original position/pointer that was passed in. If you later add something to the function, you can always reassign, or assign a new pointer based off `str`.